# If $ tan (B) $ = $\frac{n\sin (A)\cos (A)} {1-n(\cos (A))^2}$ ,then $\tan(A+B)$ equal to $?$

Tags: trigonometry

> If  $$ \tan (B)= \frac{n\sin (A)\cos (A)} {1-n\cos^2 (A)},$$ then $\tan(A+B)$ equal to $?$

I have no idea how to solve this problem.
Please help me to solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This is for other users: Shouldn't be this type of question **with no input** needs to get downvote? I am confused... why got a upvote?

Comment: well... M.Rawat. do you know $\tan(A+B) = \frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: you have $$\tan B = \frac{n\tan A}{1 - (n-1)\tan^2A}.$$

$$\tan(A+B) = \frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan{A}+\frac{n\sin{A}\cos{A}}{1-n\cos^2A}}{1-\frac{n\tan{A}\sin{A}\cos{A}}{1-n\cos^2A}}=\frac{\tan{A}-n\sin{A}\cos{A}+n\sin{A}\cos{A}}{1-n\cos^2A-n\sin^2A}=\frac{\tan{A}}{1-n}$$